# Custom array object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm new to prototyping and instantiations and therefore had a question :

- How can I create a function that constructs a new array that also has some properties added with prototype but without modifying the default Array function ?

For example :

```
function Cool_Object() {
    this = new Array() // Construct new array.
    //This is only for the example. I know you can't do that.
}
Cool_Object.prototype.my_method = function() {
    // Some method added
};
```

So, if you call :

```
var myObject = new Cool_Object();
```

myObject would be an array and have a method called "`my_method`" (which actually calls a function).

But the default Array object would be intact.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You [can't extend `Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got it a bit backwards. Just use `Array.prototype` as your custom object's prototype.

```
function Cool_Object() {

    this.my_method = function () {
        return 42;
    }
}

Cool_Object.prototype = Array.prototype;

var foo = new Cool_Object();
foo.my_method(); // 42
foo.push(13);
foo[0]; // 13
```

You can get both `Array.prototype` and `my_method` on `Cool_Object`'s prototype, without modifying `Array.prototype`, by introducing an intermediate type:

```
function Even_Cooler() {}
Even_Cooler.prototype = Array.prototype;

function Cool_Object() {}
Cool_Object.prototype = new Even_Cooler();

Cool_Object.prototype.my_method = function () {
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok I understand what you meant now. Thank you both bfavaretoo and Matt Ball very much. I didn't knew that you could use Array.prototype like this !

Comment: `Cool_Object.prototype = Array.prototype;`: Then you should not extend `Cool_Object.prototype` though. Better: `Cool_Object.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);`.

Comment: I don't understand the difference. Can you explain it ? Other question, if you use a `for ... in` loop on Cool_Object, is it possible to not loop through the `length` and `my_method` properties ? Thanks !

Comment: @Felix King - Why not `Cool_Object.prototype = [];`? That's what I did in my answer - is it wrong?

Comment: Or should I just use a normal `for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {}` loop instead of "reading" properties like a `for ... in` loop ?

Comment: @Richard: I guess in this case it really does not make a big difference, but generally, you don't want to create a new instance of the parent class at this moment, you just want to get the parent class' prototype in the prototype chain.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I think if the prototype is `[]` and you try to use, say, `splice` on a method, it's an extra step when looking up the prototype chain.

Comment: It's strange. While using the code in the second part of Matt's answers, I `console.log()` a variable that was constructed with `new Cool_Object()` and in the results, `length` was one of the properties compared to an array where `length` is not shown. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't just assign to `this`, it doesn't work and throws a `ReferenceError`. Just make `Cool_Object` extend `Array`.

One way to do that:

```
var Cool_Object = Object.create(Array.prototype);
Cool_Object.my_method = function() {
    // Some method added
};
```

Then create further objects with

```
var obj = Object.create(Cool_Object);
```

Comment: nice! can you explain how does array indexed properties actually defined in their prototype? what if we need only to have just this special behaviour (access to items by index) not all other methods defined in array prototype like as push, concat, join, reduce,...

Comment: If you need a length, it has to inherit from array. Otherwise you can use plain objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array as the function's prototype, so that your new type "inherits" from Array, and then introduce new methods in the prototype:

```
function CustomArray() {}

CustomArray.prototype = [];

// introduce a new method to your custom array type
CustomArray.prototype.total = function() {
    return this.reduce(function(ret, el) {
        return ret+el;
    }, 0);
};

// introduce another new method to your custom array type
CustomArray.prototype.arithmetiMean = function() {
    return this.total()/this.length;
};
```

Alternately you could introduce those methods in new instances:

```
function CustomArray() {
    // introduce a new method to your custom array object
    this.total = function() {
        return this.reduce(function(ret, el) {
            return ret+el;
        }, 0);
    };

    // introduce another new method to your custom array object    
    this.arithmetiMean = function() {
        return this.total()/this.length;
    };
}

CustomArray.prototype = [];

var arr = new CustomArray();

arr.push(1); // push is an array-standard method
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);
arr.push(4);
arr.push(5);
arr.push(6);
arr.push(7);
arr.push(8);
arr.push(9);
arr.push(10);

console.log(arr.arithmetiMean());
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding this for reference,  since  Object.create   is supported in most browsers these days,  a good way to make your own array object would be like this:

```
function MyCustomArray(){

}

MyCustomArray.prototype = $.extend(Object.create(Array.prototype), {
    /* example of creating own method */
    evenonly : function(){
        return this.filter(function(value){return (value % 2 == 0);});
    },

    /* example for overwriting existing method */
    push : function(value){
        console.log('Quit pushing me around!');

        return Array.prototype.push.call(this, value);
    }
});

var myca = new MyCustomArray();
myca instanceof MyCustomArray /*true*/
myca instanceof Array /*true*/
myca instanceof Object /*true*/
myca.push(1); /*Quit pushing me around!*/
myca.push(2); /*Quit pushing me around!*/
myca.push(3); /*Quit pushing me around!*/
myca.push(4); /*Quit pushing me around!*/
myca.push(5); /*Quit pushing me around!*/
myca.push(6); /*Quit pushing me around!*/

myca.length; /*6*/
myca.evenonly() /*[2, 4, 6]*/
```

Using jQuery's $.extend, because it's convenient to keep code structured, but there's no need for it, you could do this instead:

MyCustomArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

MyCustomArray.prototype.push = function(){...}

I much prefer defining the methods on the prototype rather than putting them inside the constructor.  It's cleaner and saves your custom array object from being cluttered with unnecessary functions.

Comment: Your `length` only has the expected value because you used `push`, not because `myca` is an array.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function PseudoArray() {

};
PseudoArray.prototype = Object.defineProperties(Object.create(Array.prototype), {
 constructor: {value:PseudoArray}
})
```